# Insert function inside list with arguments and use them

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have a parameter like this: 
`params={
'arg1':'a',
'arg2:'b',
'funcList':['x','y','z']}`

How to properly insert them to a function so it can be called like this:

```
func(x(a,b),y(a,b),z(a,b))
```

maybe I have to map and unpack them first, but how to do it in pythonic way?

**EDIT II:**

Here's to picture more of the case:

```
def X(a,b): # could be more args
   print(a+b)

def Y(a,b): # could be more args
   print(a*b)

# etc more funcs with identical args
```

Define the calling function could be like this:

```
def func(X,Y): # or maybe with *args?
   print("args delivered")
```

And calling the `func` could be like this:

```
func(X(1,2),Y(1,2)) # X's and Y's arguments are always identical
```

It all rooted from a single data,

```
params={
'a' :1,
'b' :2,
'funcList':['x','y']}
```

Result:

```
2
2
args delivered
```

Thank you.

Comment: So...for all the functions in `funcList`, you want to call them on the arguments in `params`?

Comment: Yup, right now it's only arg1 and arg2, but more might be added

Comment: It is not clear, what are your inputs and what is the expected output. Could you please try to reformulate the question?

Comment: the `def` behind `func(x(a,b),y(a,b),z(a,b))` means that you're at function definition level which means that you can't use python objects instead of its arguments.

Comment: that isn't a list of functions, its a list of strings

Comment: Ahh.. apologize, fixed the question

Comment: Do you want to call every function inside `funcList` with `arg1` and `arg2`? or do you want to put every function in `funcList` with the parameters `arg1` and `arg2` as a parameter inside another function?

Comment: why a list of funcs and not a list of args? This is illed-structured.

Comment: @OuuGii , it's more the second case, every `funcList` will have its args, I'll update more clearly when not on phone, but that's in the nutshell.

Comment: I've updated my question and will try the answers suggestion, but for any more concise solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
params={
   'arg1':'a',
   'arg2':'b',
   'funcList':['x','y','z']
}

result = func(*[
    eval(f)(*[arg for key, arg in sorted(list(params.items())) if key != 'funcList'])
    for f in params['funcList']
])
```

Comment: I see your point, but the args don't have to be in `arg` keyword as in my latest edit,  Thank you, I'll give it a twist and try.

Comment: Fixed! (Also the order is important I used `sorted` hoping the key hints the order.

Comment: thank you, this should be the most pythonic way, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
def call(params):
    p = params.copy()
    return map(lambda i: i(*p.values()), p.pop("funcList"))
```

Example usage:

```
>>> x = lambda arg1, arg2, arg3: arg1 + arg2 + arg3
>>> params={'arg1':'a', 'arg2':'b', 'arg3': 'c', 'funcList':[x]}
>>> list(call(params))
['abc’]
```

Then you can call your function like this:

```
>>> f = lambda i: print(i)
>>> f(*call(params))
abc
```

If the values in `params[“funcList”]` are strings, rather than actual functions, you need do add an `eval` to `call`:

```
def call(params):
    p = params.copy()
    return map(lambda i: eval(i)(*p.values()), p.pop("funcList"))
```

Comment: Thank you, but if I try to add more than 1 function like Y, it says error `NameError: name 'Y' is not defined`

Comment: aah.. I'm an idiot, of course I have to define Y first

Answer (score 0):

I gave credit to @rassar for ideas and I'll just put here to put the breakdown and what's really happening for those who still clueless ( like I was ):

```
from itertools import chain # just for showing purpose

params={'arg1':'a','arg2':'b','arg3':'c','funcList':['A','B']}

def A(*args):
  yield f'{args[-1]}' + f'{args[0]}'

def B(*args):
  yield f'{args[0]}' + f'{args[-1]}'

list(chain(A('a','b','c'),B('a','b','c'))) # my intention with params
# result: ['ca', 'ac']

# could also be expressed with creating a new tuple:

toCall=(A('a','b','c'),B('a','b','c'))

# and use it like so:

list(chain(*toCall))
# result: ['ca', 'ac']
```

With @rassar's:

```
def call(params):
    p = params.copy()
    return map(lambda i: eval(i)(*p.values()), p.pop("funcList"))

list(chain(*call(params)))
```